# Android Progress Dialog not showing until the function finish running (AsyncTask)

Tags: android, progressdialog

When a button is clicked I'm calling the async class in a function and I need to show progressDialog until it runs the displaylist function. But it shows up only after the function finished running and closes immediately. Please help me what am I doing wrong here.

```
public class FilterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dispProgress;

     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dispProgress = ProgressDialog.show(Filter.this, "Please wait...",
                    "Loading...", true, true);
        }

       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

           return null;
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);

        MerchantsActivity.displayList();
            dispProgress.cancel();
            finish();
       }

    }
```

Comment: You are using this as a subclass right ?

Comment: Yes I'm using this as a subclass

Answer (score 1):

Your AsyncTask will complete immediately because you do exactly nothing in doInBackground()! That's where your long-running background non-UI code is supposed to go...

Comment: MerchantsActivity.displaylist() is the function that takes a lot of time to load. when I put that function in doInBackground() it throws a runtime exception

Comment: Probably because it does UI stuff which can only be done on the UI thread. You need to redesign MerchantsActivity.displayList() into a part that can run entirely in the background (i.e. in doInBackground), and a part that simply updates the UI (which runs in onProgressUpdate and/or onPostExecute)

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a solution. Is there any other way I can handle this?.. because dividing it into parts will require a lot of code changes.

Comment: It depends what displayList() actually does. I do advise you to get into the habit of keeping UI code and objects as separate as possible from everything else (i.e. your data).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to use the `static ProgressDialog#show` method. Rather do`new ProgressDialog()` and initialize it accordingly and finally call `show()`. I have never used the static method and do not know how it works, but I have used the other option. Furthermore the static method seems to have no available documentation.